# In each next LI inside UL make data-attribute value higher for x value

Tags: jquery, html

I have UL list with Lis inside.
I want to make in first LI data-value="0.3s"
In second 0.6 , in third 0.9 and so on.... of course with JavaScript or jQuery, so in html I have only

and using jQuery add data-attributes and values

So result would be

```
<li data-value=0.3s> - first
<li data-value=0.6s> - second
<li data-value=0.9s> - third
<li data-value=1.2s> - fourth
<li data-value=1.5s> - fifth
<li data-value=1.8s> - sixth
```

**Also, is it possible to add add for first 4 increase, then on fifth reset and startin again.**

Result for this would be:

```
<li data-value=0.3s> - first
<li data-value=0.6s> - second
<li data-value=0.9s> - third
<li data-value=1.2s> - fourth
<li data-value=0.3s> - fifth (reset)
<li data-value=0.6s> - sixth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

```
var counter = 0;
$('ul > li').each( function() {
   $(this).attr('data-value', ++counter * 0.3 +'s');
});
```

2)

```
var counter = -1;
$('ul > li').each( function() {
   $(this).attr('data-value', ( (++counter % 4) + 1) * 0.3 +'s');
});
```

U want sth like this?

Comment: In a first version I forgot about `()` and `});` ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible solution,

In the code below, I have provided a text box where you can provide the index where 'value' needs to be reset. Then, click on the 'Apply Value' button to see the value in that specific index. Let me know if you need more information.

```js
$('#Start').on('click', function(){
  
 var resetIndexValue = $('#ResetIndex').val();

 var lielements = $('ul > li');
  
 var current = 0.0;
  
  $.each(lielements, function(i, li){
    
    if (resetIndexValue == i)
      {
        current = 0.0;        
      }
    
    current = current + 0.3;
    
    $(li).data('value', current + 's');
      
    });
  
  $('#IndexValue').text($(lielements[resetIndexValue]).data('value')); //'
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-value=''></li>
  <li data-value=''></li>
  <li data-value=''></li>
  <li data-value=''></li>
  <li data-value=''></li>
  <li data-value=''></li>
</ul>

Reset At Index: <input type="text" id="ResetIndex" />
<button id="Start">Apply Value</button>
<label id="IndexValue"></label>
```